# How to calculate the area of a 4 dimensional curve?

Tags: physics

I have been searching on Google about it, and I found that given a sample, 4 points, per example, I could find a function and use integral on it.

I am sorry if it sounds silly, I am very dummy in mathematics.  How could I find the area of this curve?

#### Clarification

I want to know the length of the trajectory of the center of an object moving in 3-dimensional space.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do?  Curves don't have area.

Comment: Cold you also perhaps provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, well, perhaps you can help me with, then: I have a four dimensions chart: height, width, depth, and time. I would like to know how much an object was moved, during a time lapse.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: so you want to know the length of the trajectory of the center of an object moving in 3-dimensional space?

Comment: Yeah! That's it!

Comment: How do you define the curve? (Just by four points on the curve?)

Comment: As I am analysing per sample, per example 4 or 5 at each time, I could use a line, instead of a curve.

Comment: I think it would be simpler and not astray too much from the real data

Comment: But yes, just a quantity of coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the comments they helped. I've found the solution:
√((x2−x1)^2+(y2−y1)^2+(z2−z1)^2)

It was just a simple case of of getting the length of 3d diagonals.

Thank you very much for the help.

src: http://www.intmath.com/vectors/6-3-dimensional-space.php

Comment: I think you may be more interested in this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating

Comment: Wow, I am amazed...